# How to find second level connections of a user in mysql like linkedin?

Tags: mysql, self-join

I need to write a query to fetch second level connections of a user.

Suppose there are four friends:A, B, C, D

```
A is friend with B
B is friend with C and D
```

Now i want to find second level connections for A i.e C and D

Database Design

Table: users

```
id name
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
```

Table: user_friends

```
id  friend1  friend2
1    1        2
2    2        3
3    2        4
```

Anyone to help me with query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM users AS u, user_friends AS a, user_friends AS b, users as f
WHERE u.name='A' AND u.id != f.id AND
  ((u.id = a.friend1 AND a.friend2 = b.friend1 AND b.friend2 = f.id) OR
   (u.id = a.friend1 AND a.friend2 = b.friend2 AND b.friend1 = f.id) OR
   (u.id = a.friend2 AND a.friend1 = b.friend1 AND b.friend2 = f.id) OR
   (u.id = a.friend2 AND a.friend1 = b.friend2 AND b.friend1 = f.id));
```

Comment: Thanks :). Is there any other way to solve it? Actually someone has asked me the question in a interview.

Comment: Lol. There are almost always other ways to solve it. This case being no different.